# AngularJS, get single post from json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJS but are stuck in, probably, a simple issue.

I have some hardcoded json files so far, no "real" backend yet,with some persons in it. In my form I want to display a single person everytime. All the examples I've found use query to fetch lists or calls a REST service with parameters. I'm not sure how to apply this on my prototype?
This code works in that way that it fetches my json file and display the single entity in it, but when there's 10 of them I would like to search for one. Next step will be to do "like" searches and diaplsy them in a modal list.. I think..

My html

```
.......
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="inputId" class="col-lg-2 control-label">PersonId</label>
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputId" ng-model="person.personid">
 </div>
<button class="btn btn-mc" ng-click="getPerson()">Search</button> 
</div>
```

My Controller

```
.........
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'Person', function($scope, Person) {
            $scope.person = Person.get();
```

My Service

```
 angular.module('myApp.personServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Person', ['$resource',
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource('persons/person.json/:personid', {}, {
                get: {method:'GET', isArray:false}
                });
            }]);
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Could this example be of any use?
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

If you will be dealing with lots of data, you will have to do the filtering server-side. Can't afford to load millions of entries into memory and then start filtering.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, maybe this is the easiest way to solve the issue with my prototype. As you say, in the "real world" there will be a real REST backend that will handle that part. Then I would need to load the whole json in "init", and display nothing in my form until user write a personId and push the "search button"